# How to clone Windows Server 2012 r2 DNS Server configuration from one server to another?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to export all the configuration settings from a "corporate" DNS server to my local DNS server (both systems use Windows Server 2012 r2) for testing and I am unsure as for how to do that. I explored `dnscmd` and the `dnscmd /exportsettings` (all this does write server configuration information to a text file) but haven't had much luck finding a solution.

I have also tried using a backup (http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=1837) and restore script (http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=1858) but these scripts only backup/restore zone files and not other configuration settings such as conditional forwarders, etc.

What would be the best way to go about solving my problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zone information and DNS server settings are in different places.

- Non-AD-integrated DNS server stores its **zones** as `.dns` files in `%windir%\system32\dns`. Copy these files besides `cache.dns`, that only contains cached DNS lookups.

  With AD-integrated DNS server the information is within AD and `dns.exe` performs many LDAP requests to gather this data when it starts. It's possible to [Extract Active Directory-Integrated Zone Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/304489/extracting-dns-active-directory-integrated-zone-files) with `dnscmd /ZoneExport FQDN_of_zonename Zone_export_file`, like you have done.
- **Settings are stored in the registry.** Things are easy when AD isn't involved, as you can just export the settings with `regedit /e` and import by double clicking the `.reg` file on the target server. With AD-integrated installation you may need to check some values manually before importing. However, here's some registry locations where you can find your server settings:

  - `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\DNS Server\Zones` (formerly `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\DNS\Zones`) 
    is the location in the registry related to the zone files: what zones
    the server has, what are their settings and where they should be
    obtained from. The same information that can be obtained with [`dnscmd /zoneinfo`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772069(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_26).
  - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DNS\Parameters` is the location for server-level settings. It's the same information that can be obtained with [`dnscmd /info`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772069(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_12).
  - The other [DNS Registry Entries](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd197418(v=ws.10).aspx) aren't directly associated with the DNS Server.

Comment: .dns files only exist if the DNS zones are **not** AD integrated.

Comment: Yeah this won't really work...

Comment: I hope my answer is more complete now.